# xpath: preceding-sibling-or-self

Tags: .net, xpath

I'd like `preceding-sibling-or-self` functionality in my xpath and I'm using `../(self::*|preceding-sibling::*)` and it's giving me `Expression must evaluate to a node-set.`, so I must be doing it wrong.

This bombs no matter what context node you are on or what the xml looks like. I want to use this functionality after a `/` so I need the right syntax for that.

The xpath expression `(self::*|preceding-sibling::*)` does not give an error, so it has to do with the place in the xpath which I'm trying to use it.

EDIT:

My mistake is actually more basic. You can't even do `../(.|.)` without that error. In general, I want to go to a node, then look through a set of nodes from there. The error seems to correlate with trying to use the union operator `|` after a slash `/`.

Comment: The syntax you are trying to use is valid in XPath 2.0, but not 1.0. I don't think there is a good way to accomplish this in a single path. In what context are you using these expressions? With `XmlNode.SelectNodes()`? Or in an XSLT?

Comment: @JLRishe, `XmlNode.SelectNodes`. It's not pretty; I put an answer below :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In XPath, if you want to use the union operator, you must use it at the beginning of the path.

`(self::*|preceding-sibling::*)/Child` is ok.

If you need to do `Something/(self::*|preceding-sibling::*)/Child`, you have to expand the left part out like this:

`(Something/self::*|Something/preceding-sibling::*)/Child`