# Excel - Extract substring(s) from string using FILTERXML

Tags: arrays, excel, xml, xpath, excel-formula

***<sub>Background</sub>***

Lately I've been trying to get more familiar with the concept of changing a delimited string into an XML to parse with Excel's [`FILTERXML`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filterxml-function-4df72efc-11ec-4951-86f5-c1374812f5b7) and retrieve those substrings that are of interest. Please note that this function came available from Excel 2013 and is not available on Excel for Mac nor Excel Online.

With a delimited string, I meant anything from a normal sentence using spaces as delimiters or any other combination of characters that could be used to define substrings within a string. For example let's imagine the following:

```
ABC|123|DEF|456|XY-1A|ZY-2F|XY-3F|XY-4f|xyz|123
```

---

***<sub>Question</sub>***

So, where a lot of people know how to get the *nth* element (e.g.: `=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"|",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),3*LEN(A1)+1,LEN(A1)))` to retrieve `456`). Or other combinationes with `LEN()`, `MID()`, `FIND()` and all those constructs, how do we use `FILTERXML` to use more specific criteria to extract substrings of concern and clean up the full string? For example, how to retrieve:

- elements by position
- numeric or non-numeric elements
- elements that contain a substring on their own
- elements that start or end with a substring
- elements that are upper- or lowercase
- elements holding numbers
- unique values
- ...

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Excel's `FILTERXML` uses `XPATH 1.0` which unfortunately means it is not as diverse as we would maybe want it to be. Also, Excel seems to ***not*** allow returning reworked node values and exclusively allows you to select nodes in order of appearance. However there is a fair share of functions we can still utilize. More information about that can be found [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/).

The function takes two parameters: `=FILTERXML(<A string in valid XML format>,<A string in valid XPATH format>)`

Let's say cell `A1` holds the string: `ABC|123|DEF|456|XY-1A|ZY-2F|XY-3F|XY-4f|xyz|123`. To create a valid XML string we use `SUBSTITUTE` to change the delimiter to valid end- and start-tag constructs. So to get a valid XML construct for the given example we could do:

`"<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"|","</s><s>")&"</s></t>"`

For readability reasons I'll refer to the above construct with the word **`<XML>`** as a *placeholder*. Below you'll find different usefull `XPATH` functions in a valid construct to filter nodes:

---

<sub>***1) All Elements:***</sub>

```
=FILTERXML(<XML>,"//s")
```

<sub>Returns: `ABC`, `123`, `DEF`, `456`, `XY-1A`, `ZY-2F`, `XY-3F`, `XY-4f`, `xyz` and `123` (all nodes)</sub>

---

<sub>***2) Elements by position:***</sub>

```
=FILTERXML(<XML>,"//s[position()=4]")
```

Or:

```
=FILTERXML(<XML>,"//s[4]")
```

<sub>Returns: `456` (node on index 4)</sub><sup>†</sup>

```
=FILTERXML(<XML>,"//s[position()<4]")
```

<sub>Returns: `ABC`, `123` and `DEF` (nodes on index < 4)</sub>

```
=FILTERXML(<XML>,"//s[position()=2 or position()>5]")
```

<sub>Returns: `123`, `ZY-2F`, `XY-3F`, `XY-4f`, `xyz` and `123` (nodes on index 2 or > 5)</sub>

```
=FILTERXML(<XML>,"//s[last()]")
```

<sub>Returns: `123` (node on last index)</sub>

```
=FILTERXML(<XML>,"//s[position() mod 2 = 1]")
```

<sub>Returns: `ABC`, `DEF`, `XY-1A`, `XY-3F` and `xyz` (odd nodes)</sub>

```
=FILTERXML(<XML>,"//s[position() mod 2 = 0]")
```

<sub>Returns: `123`, `456`, `ZF-2F`, `XY-4f` and `123` (even nodes)</sub>

---

<sub>***3) (Non) numeric elements:***</sub>

```
=FILTERXML(<XML>,"//s[number()=.]")
```

Or:

```
=FILTERXML(<XML>,"//s[.*0=0]")
```

<sub>Returns: `123`, `456`,  and `123` (numeric nodes)</sub>

```
=FILTERXML(<XML>,"//s[not(number()=.)]")
```

Or:

```
=FILTERXML(<XML>,"//s[.*0!=0)]")
```

<sub>Returns: `ABC`, `DEF`, `XY-1A`, `ZY-2F`, `XY-3F`, `XY-4f` and `xyz` (non-numeric nodes)</sub>

---

<sub>***4) Elements that (not) contain:***</sub>

```
=FILTERXML(<XML>,"//s[contains(., 'Y')]")
```

<sub>Returns: `XY-1A`, `ZY-2F`, `XY-3F` and `XY-4f` (containing 'Y', notice `XPATH` is case sensitive, exclusing `xyz`)</sub>

```
=FILTERXML(<XML>,"//s[not(contains(., 'Y'))]")
```

<sub>Returns: `ABC`, `123`, `DEF`, `456`, `xyz` and `123` (not containing 'Y', notice `XPATH` is case sensitive, including `xyz`)</sub>

---

<sub>***5) Elements that (not) start or/and end with:***</sub>

```
=FILTERXML(<XML>,"//s[starts-with(., 'XY')]")
```

<sub>Returns: `XY-1A`, `XY-3F` and `XY-4f` (starting with 'XY')</sub>

```
=FILTERXML(<XML>,"//s[not(starts-with(., 'XY'))]")
```

<sub>Returns: `ABC`, `123`, `DEF`, `456`, `ZY-2F`, `xyz` and `123` (don't start with 'XY')</sub>

```
=FILTERXML(<XML>,"//s[substring(., string-length(.) - string-length('F') +1) = 'F']")
```

<sub>Returns: `DEF`, `ZY-2F` and `XY-3F` (end with 'F', notice `XPATH 1.0` does not support `ends-with`)</sub>

```
=FILTERXML(<XML>,"//s[not(substring(., string-length(.) - string-length('F') +1) = 'F')]")
```

<sub>Returns: `ABC`, `123`, `456`, `XY-1A`, `XY-4f`, `xyz` and `123` (don't end with 'F')</sub>

```
=FILTERXML(<XML>,"//s[starts-with(., 'X') and substring(., string-length(.) - string-length('A') +1) = 'A']")
```

<sub>Returns: `XY-1A` (start with 'X' and end with 'A')</sub>

---

<sub>***6) Elements that are upper- or lowercase:***</sub>

```
=FILTERXML(<XML>,"//s[translate(.,'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz','ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')=.]")
```

<sub>Returns: `ABC`, `123`, `DEF`, `456`, `XY-1A`, `ZY-2F`, `XY-3F` and `123` (uppercase nodes)</sub>

```
=FILTERXML(<XML>,"//s[translate(.,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')=.]")
```

<sub>Returns: `123`, `456`, `xyz` and `123` (lowercase nodes)</sub>

<sub>**NOTE:** Unfortunately `XPATH 1.0` does not support `upper-case()` nor `lower-case()` so the above is a workaround. Add special characters if need be.</sub>

---

<sub>***7) Elements that (not) contain any number:***</sub>

```
=FILTERXML(<XML>,"//s[translate(.,'1234567890','')!=.]")
```

<sub>Returns: `123`, `456`, `XY-1A`, `ZY-2F`, `XY-3F`, `XY-4f` and `123` (contain any digit)</sub>

```
=FILTERXML(<XML>,"//s[translate(.,'1234567890','')=.]")
```

<sub>Returns: `ABC`, `DEF` and `xyz` (don't contain any digit)</sub>

```
=FILTERXML(<XML>,"//s[translate(.,'1234567890','')!=. and .*0!=0]")
```

<sub>Returns: `XY-1A`, `ZY-2F`, `XY-3F` and `XY-4f` (holding digits but not a a number on it's own)</sub>

---

<sub>***8) Unique elements or duplicates:***</sub>

```
=FILTERXML(<XML>,"//s[preceding::*=.]")
```

<sub>Returns: `123` (duplicate nodes)</sub>

```
=FILTERXML(<XML>,"//s[not(preceding::*=.)]")
```

<sub>Returns: `ABC`, `123`, `DEF`, `456`, `XY-1A`, `ZY-2F`, `XY-3F`, `XY-4f` and `xyz` (unique nodes)</sub>

```
=FILTERXML(<XML>,"//s[not(following::*=. or preceding::*=.)]")
```

<sub>Returns: `ABC`, `DEF`, `456`, `XY-1A`, `ZY-2F`, `XY-3F` and `XY-4f` (nodes that have no similar sibling)</sub>

---

<sub>***9) Elements of certain length:***</sub>

```
=FILTERXML(<XML>,"//s[string-length()=5]")
```

<sub>Returns: `XY-1A`, `ZY-2F`, `XY-3F` and `XY-4f` (5 characters long)</sub>

```
=FILTERXML(<XML>,"//s[string-length()<4]")
```

<sub>Returns: `ABC`, `123`, `DEF`, `456`, `xyz` and `123` (shorter than 4 characters)</sub>

---

<sub>***10) Elements based on preceding/following:***</sub>

```
=FILTERXML(<XML>,"//s[preceding::*[1]='456']")
```

<sub>Returns: `XY-1A` (previous node equals '456')</sub>

```
=FILTERXML(<XML>,"//s[starts-with(preceding::*[1],'XY')]")
```

<sub>Returns: `ZY-2F`, `XY-4f`, and `xyz` (previous node starts with 'XY')</sub>

```
=FILTERXML(<XML>,"//s[following::*[1]='123']")
```

<sub>Returns: `ABC`, and `xyz` (following node equals '123')</sub>

```
=FILTERXML(<XML>,"//s[contains(following::*[1],'1')]")
```

<sub>Returns: `ABC`, `456`, and `xyz` (following node contains '1')</sub>

```
=FILTERXML(<XML>,"//s[preceding::*='ABC' and following::*='XY-3F']")
```

Or:

```
=FILTERXML(<XML>,"//s[.='ABC']/following::s[following::s='XY-3F']")
```

<sub>Returns: `123`, `DEF`, `456`, `XY-1A` and `ZY-2F` (everything between 'ABC' and 'XY-3F')</sub>

---

<sub>***11) Elements based on sub-strings:***</sub>

```
=FILTERXML(<XML>,"//s[substring-after(., '-') = '3F']")
```

<sub>Returns: `XY-3F` (nodes ending with '3F' after hyphen)</sub>

```
=FILTERXML(<XML>,"//s[contains(substring-after(., '-') , 'F')]")
```

<sub>Returns: `ZY-2F` and `XY-3F` (nodes containing 'F' after hyphen)</sub>

```
=FILTERXML(<XML>,"//s[substring-before(., '-') = 'ZY']")
```

<sub>Returns: `ZY-2F` (nodes starting with 'ZY' before hyphen)</sub>

```
=FILTERXML(<XML>,"//s[contains(substring-before(., '-'), 'Y')]")
```

<sub>Returns: `XY-1A`, `ZY-2F`, `XY-3F` and `XY-4f` (nodes containing 'Y' before hyphen)</sub>

---

<sub>***12) Elements based on concatenation:***</sub>

```
=FILTERXML(<XML>,"//s[concat(., '|', following::*[1])='ZY-2F|XY-3F']")
```

<sub>Returns: `ZY-2F` (nodes when concatenated with '|' and following sibling equals 'ZY-2F|XY-3F')</sub>

```
=FILTERXML(<XML>,"//s[contains(concat(., preceding::*[2]), 'FA')]")
```

<sub>Returns: `DEF` (nodes when concatenated with sibling two indices to the left contains 'FA')</sub>

---

<sub>***13) Empty vs. Non-empty:***</sub>

```
=FILTERXML(<XML>,"//s[count(node())>0]")
```

Or:

```
=FILTERXML(<XML>,"//s[node()]")
```

<sub>Returns: `ABC`, `123`, `DEF`, `456`, `XY-1A`, `ZY-2F`, `XY-3F`, `XY-4f`, `xyz` and `123` (all nodes that are not empty)</sub>

```
=FILTERXML(<XML>,"//s[count(node())=0]")
```

Or:

```
=FILTERXML(<XML>,"//s[not(node())]")
```

<sub>Returns: None (all nodes that are empty)</sub>

---

<sub>***14) Preceding or Following:***</sub>

```
=FILTERXML(<XML>,"//s[substring(., string-length(.) - string-length('F') +1) = 'F'][last()]/following::*")
```

<sub>Returns: `XY-4f`, `xyz` and `123` (all nodes to the right of the **last** node that ends with an uppercase 'F')</sub>

```
=FILTERXML(<XML>,"//s[substring(., string-length(.) - string-length('F') +1) = 'F'][1]/preceding::*")
```

<sub>Returns: `ABC` and `123` (all nodes to the left of the **first** node that ends with an uppercase 'F')</sub>

---

<sub>***15) (Preceding or Following) and self:***</sub>

```
=FILTERXML(<XML>,"(//s[.*0!=0][last()]|//s[.*0!=0][last()]/preceding::*)")
```

<sub>Returns: `ABC`, `123`, `DEF`, `456`, `XY-1A`, `ZY-2F`, `XY-3F`, `XY-4f` and `xyz` (trim all numeric nodes from the right)</sub><sup>††</sup>

```
=FILTERXML(<XML>,"(//s[.*0=0][1]|//s[.*0=0][1]/following::*)")
```

<sub>Returns: `123`, `DEF`, `456`, `XY-1A`, `ZY-2F`, `XY-3F`, `XY-4f`, `xyz` and `123` (trim all non-numeric nodes from the left)</sub>

---

<sub>***16) Maximum or Minimum:***</sub>

```
=FILTERXML(<XML>,"(//s[.*0=0][not(.<//s)])[1]")
```

<sub>Returns: `456` (The maximum value looking at numeric nodes)</sub>

```
=FILTERXML(<XML>,"(//s[.*0=0][not(.>//s)])[1]")
```

<sub>Returns: `123` (The minimum value looking at numeric nodes)</sub>

<sub>**NOTE:** This is the equivalent to returning all numeric nodes as per #3 and post-process the array using Excel's `MIN()` and `MAX()` functions.</sub>

---

Now obviously the above is a demonstration of possibilities with `XPATH 1.0` functions and you can get a whole range of combinations of the above and more! I tried to cover most commonly used string functions. If you are missing any please feel free to comment.

Whereas the question is quite broad on itself, I was hoping to give some general direction on how to use `FILTERXML` for the queries at hand. The formula returns an array of nodes to be used in any other way. A lot of the times I would use it in `TEXTJOIN()` or `INDEX()`. But I guess other options would be new DA-functions to spill results.

Be alert that while parsing a string through `FILTERXML()`, the ampersand character (&) and the left angle bracket (<) must [**not**](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#syntax) appear in their literal form. They will respectively need to be substituted with either `&amp;` or `&lt;`. Another option would be to use their numeric ISO/IEC 10646 character [code](https://m.tonysweb.be/ISO_IEC%2010646-12000(E).html) being `&#38;` or `&#60;` respectively. After parsing, the function will return these characters back to you in their literal form. Needless to say that splitting a string by the semi-colon therefor just became tricky.

---

<sup>‡</sup> <sub>Each predicate, the structure between the opening and closing square brackets, is a filter of a given nodelist. To write multiple of these structures is in fact [**and**ing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62969654/xpath-what-do-nested-square-brackets-mean/62970207#62970207) such predicates.</sub>

<sup>‡‡</sup> <sub>There isn't really an easy, following/preceding siblings **and** self, construct. Therefor I used the [Union](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/xml/xpath/xpath-union-operator-example/) operator. This, however, requires multiple expressions to be inside [paranthesis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26598269/9758194). Much like alternations within a capture group if one would think about regular expressions.</sub>

Comment: FYI You might be interested in a tricky way to change a digits string into a sorted array of unique digits via `FilterXML`, enriched by some explanations (as well as a link to the above post :-) at [Divide numbers into unique sorted digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63540928/divide-numbers-into-unique-sorted-digits-displayed-in-a-label-on-a-userform) - @JvdV

Comment: When we can filter numeric nodes only by `=FILTERXML(<XML>,"//s[.*0=0]")`. Can we apply condition here like I want filter numeric nodes `<200`?

Comment: @Harun24HR, yes you can use [logical operators](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_operators.asp) like "less then". You can directly apply e.g: `=FILTERXML(<XML>,"//s[.<200]")` in the above example which would return both "123"-nodes.

Comment: @JvdV That works fine! Honestly saying I have learned about `FILTERXML()` from your this post. Grateful to you.

Comment: this is an excellent reference - well, done, @JvdV.

Comment: @JvdV Fyi Whereas top post focusses on the tabular Syntax with a nearly encyclopaedic number of XPath examples, it might be of some interest how to handle **results** in (dynamic) VBA: [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69637009/getting-3-digits-from-a-set-of-numbers-using-regex-for-vba/69645093#69645093)

Comment: I have seen that post this morning (and +'ed it for you). Used the function through VBA once or twice, though sparsely, myself. @T.M.

Comment: @JvdV Sir, this is just superb and mind blowing, the day you posted since then I am using it, much helpful for me!!! Gracias!!!

Comment: Hi JvdV, the FILTERXML function is not working for me anymore. Not sure if it has anything to do with the recent Excel update. Could you please let me know if you can still use the function as usual?

Comment: @TerryW, hello. I find there is nothing wrong on my end. I'm on the very latest update of Excel (365's BETA channel).

Comment: @JvdV Could you confirm that the `FilterXML` *XPath expressions* needs xmldom functions to be written only lower case - see my recent *Caveat* hint at [Find element in array ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72883948/how-to-find-an-element-in-an-array-through-a-specific-character-in-the-element/73859472#73859472)

Comment: @T.M., yes, keywords in xpath are written in lower-case. You are correct in your statement that functions will error if written differently.

Comment: Great explanation @JvdV, not I understand it better. Worth noticing that according to [FILTERXML](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filterxml-function-4df72efc-11ec-4951-86f5-c1374812f5b7) documentation as of 11/15/2022  *is not available in Excel for the web and Excel for Mac*

Answer (score 16):

**EDIT 22-3-2022**:

As per the new `TEXTSPLIT()` function, one can now split a string straight into an horizontal or vertical range (or both). It can even split on an array of values. However, it can not directly filter as 'xpath' can. Therefor I'll keep the below answer intact as it can still be relevant.

---

### The infamous missing `XSPLIT()` function

This post is meant as a little in-depth extra to show how we can make our own  re-usable `XSPLIT()` function using `FILTERXML()` but without the use of VBA. Though currently in BETA, `LAMBDA()` is comming our way and with this function we can create our own custom function. Let me explain this at the hand of an example:

[image]

The formula in `C1` is simply `=XSPLIT(A1,B1:B3)` and it spills the delimited text values in order of appearance. However `SPLIT()` is the name of our `LAMBDA()` function we created in the "name manager":

```
=LAMBDA(txt,del,[xpath],FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",,TEXTSPLIT(txt,del))&"</s></t>","//s"&xpath))
```

As you can see, the function has 4 parameters:

- `txt` - A reference to our source value.
- `del` - Any amount of delimiters we'd like. Written or referenced.
- `[xpath]` - Place for a xpath expression to apply some filter if need be. E.g: `"[.*0=0]"` to only return numeric substrings. This is an optional parameter
- `FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",,TEXTSPLIT(txt,del))&"</s></t>","//s"&xpath)`

The 4th parameter is where all the 3 previous parameters are being called to create the same construct as been covered in the main post. Now, since MS does not want to give us themselves, we created our own `XSPLIT()` function with the three parameters.

The main post concentrates on the `SUBSTITUTE()` of a specific delimiter; in the given example the pipe-symbol. But what if you have several delimiters? You'd need multiple nested `SUBSTITUTE()` functions, right? Wouldn't it be great if we can implement that in our `XSPLIT()` function too? Here is where `TEXTSPLIT()` is getting exciting for me personally because we can feed this function multiple delimiters to split a string into elements.

We have now created our own `XSPLIT()` function with three parameters:

```
=XSPLIT(<StringToBeSplited>,<YourDelimiters>,<OptionalXpath>)
```

And we can now use this as a function in our *whole* workbook. Enjoy!